# HOW TO FIx code : 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM' const { nanoid } = require("nanoid");

Tags: javascript, node.js

how to fix it ,
I'm doing App chat .
Sorry if the language is difficult to read, I'm Thai.

```
PS C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\chat\server> node server.js
C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\chat\server\server.js:4
const { nanoid } = require("nanoid");
               ^
[ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module 
C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\chat\server\node_modules\nanoid\index.js from 
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\chat\server\server.js:4:20) {
code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'



{
"name": "chat",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "server.js",
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"start": "node server.js"
},
```

"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"express": "^4.18.1",
"nanoid": "^4.0.0",
"socket.io": "^4.5.1"
}
}

Comment: maybe downgrade to version 3 https://github.com/ai/nanoid/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 15):

The problem is that you are using nanoid Ver.4.0.0 .
It seems that a new feature in V.4 (support for ESM) is a braking change.

The full documentation is in this [link to issue#365](https://github.com/ai/nanoid/issues/365#issuecomment-1188919317) in the nanoid GitHub repo.

The comment that helped me and I base my solution on was from [@salyndev0](https://github.com/ai/nanoid/issues/365#issuecomment-1188919317)

To fix the problem follow these steps:

- Uninstall nanoid: `npm uninstall nanoid`
- Install Version 3 supporting all 3.x.x:  `npm install nanoid@^3.0.0`

Answer (score 4):

This means the library you're trying to require [cannot be imported](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-error-err-require-esm-require-of-es-module-not-supported#fix---error-err_require_esm-require-not-supported) using the `require` syntax.

I think the version of the `nanoid` you're using needs to be imported using `import`

You could try downgrading `nanoid` or switching to the [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) keyword.